# put next lines in an array after finding the matched pattern in Perl

Tags: perl

I open a text report inside my **Perl script** and need to find the specific lines and store them in arrays.

```
this is my report which I need to process through:
matched pattern 1 
line1:10
line2:20
line3:30

next matched pattern 2
line1:5
line2:10
line3:15

next matched pattern 3
lineA:A
lineB:B
lineC:C
.
.
------------------------------------
```

this part is my script:

```
@numbers;
@numbers2;
@letters;
while (<FILE>)
{
 if ($_ =~/matched pattern 1/ && $_ ne "\n")
 {
   chomp();
   push (@numbers,$_)
 }
 if ($_ =~/next matched pattern 2/ && $_ ne "\n")
 {
   chomp();
   push (@numbers2,$_)
 }
 if ($_ =~/next matched pattern 3/ && $_ ne "\n")
 {
   chomp();
   push (@letters,$_)
 }
}
```

then I can use numbers and letters inside the arrays.
this is a part of my report file

```
Maximum points per Lab
Lab1:10
Lab2:30
Lab3:20


Maximum points per Exam
Exam1:50
Exam2:50

Maximum points on Final
Final:150
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your program supposed to be doing? Your current program is looking for the lines that have `matched pattern` and storing ***THOSE VERY LINEs*** into three different arrays. All other lines are ignored.

You show some sort of example output, but there's no real relationship between your output and input.

First, learn about [references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), so you don't need five different arrays. In my example, I use an array of arrays to store all of your separate files. If each file represents something else, you could use an array of hashes or a hash of arrays or a hash of hashes of arrays to represent this data in a unified structure. (Don't get me started on how you really should learn object oriented Perl. Get the hang of references first).

Also get a book on modern Perl and learn the new Perl syntax. It looks like your Perl reference is for Perl 4.0. Perl 5.0 has been out since 1994. There's a big difference between Perl 4 and Perl 5 in the way syntax is done.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Prints out your data strtucture
use Data::Dumper;

my $array_num;
my @array_of_arrays;

use constant  {
    PATTERN => qr/matched pattern/,
};

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    next if $line =~ /^\s*$/;   #Skip blank lines
    if ($line =~ PATTERN) {
        if (not defined $array_num) {
            $array_num = 0;
        }
        else {
            $array_num++;
        }
        next;
    }
    push @{ $array_of_arrays[$array_num] }, $line;
}
print Dumper (\@array_of_arrays) . "\n";

__DATA__
matched pattern 1 
line1:10
line2:20
line3:30

next matched pattern 2
line1:5
line2:10
line3:15

next matched pattern 3
lineA:A
lineB:B
lineC:C
```

OUTPUT. Each set of lines are in a different array:

```
$VAR1 = [
      [
        'line1:10',
        'line2:20',
        'line3:30'
      ],
      [
        'line1:5',
        'line2:10',
        'line3:15'
      ],
      [
        'lineA:A',
        'lineB:B',
        'lineC:C'
      ]
    ];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@numbers;
@letters;
open FILE, "report2.txt" or die $!;
while (<FILE>)
{
 if ($_ =~/:(\d+)/ && $_ ne "\n")
 {
   chomp();
   push (@numbers,$1)
 }elsif ($_ =~/:(\w+)/ && $_ ne "\n")
 {
   chomp();
   push (@letters,$1)
 }
}

print "numbers:  ", @numbers, "\n";
print "letters:  ", @letters, "\n";
```

Comment: I need to manage 5 arrays and they are pretty same except in the title, I will edit the question

Comment: @femchi I don't see a difference between patterns 1 and 2.  Is there something that distinguishes them?

Comment: when I use "while" it checks the file line by line and in my report after finding the matching pattern I need to put the next 3 lines in an array.

Comment: I added a part of my report paper.

Answer (score 1):

Revised for some best practices and my own style preferences (programmed for extensibility, as I always end up extending code, so I try to program in a generally extensible way):

```
# Things we search for
my %patterns = (
    foo => qr/^matched pattern 1/,
    bar => qr/^matched pattern 2/,
    baz => qr/^matched pattern 3/,
);

# Where we store matches, initialized to empty array refs
my %matches = map { $_ => [] } keys %patterns;

open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die $!;
my %current_match;
LINE: while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    # We never want empty lines, so exit early
    next if $_ eq "\n";

    # Check current line for matches, to note which bucket we are saving into
    for my $matchable (keys %patterns) {
        # Skip to next unless it matches
        next unless $lines =~ $matches{$matchable};

        # Set the current match and jump to next line:
        $current_match = $matchable;
        next LINE;
    }

    # If there's a current match found, save the line
    push( @{$matches{$current_match}, $line ) if $current_match;
}
```

Comment: It uses a few concepts you may not be familiar with, but spending a few minutes figuring out what's going on will probably help quite a bit in any future stuff you do in perl.  Feel free to ask about anything specific you don't get. :)

Comment: Err, also, I didn't actually test it runs, but conceptually it should work.  If there's a problem, let me know.